# When do Inverse Images of Measurable Sets Generate the $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

Just out of curiosity!

Let $(X,\mathcal{M})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{N})$ be measurable spaces and let $f: X\to Y$ be a measurable function. If $\mathcal{N}$ is generated by some collection of sets $\mathcal{E} \subset \mathcal{P}(Y),$ when can we say that $\mathcal{M}$ is generated by $f^{-1}(\mathcal{E}),$ where $f^{-1}(\mathcal{E}) = \left\{f^{-1} (E) \mid E \in \mathcal{E}\right\}?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63374/inverse-images-and-sigma-algebras/63398#63398), we have 
$$\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal E))=f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal E))=f^{-1}(\mathcal N)\subset \mathcal M,$$
but the inclusion may be strict, for example when $f$ is constant.