# If the inverse of every real open set is measurable, then the inverse of every real Borel set is also measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Assume a real-valued function f whose domain is Lebesgue-measurable. If the f inverse of every real open set is measurable, then the f inverse of every real Borel set is also measurable.

I had an incorrect solution since I assumed that every Borel set is an open set and used this idea to prove the implication. How should I go about this?

Comment: The proof may be more or less complex depending on the theorems you know. There is a theorem that says if $\mathcal{F}$ is a sigma algebra on the domain of a function $f$ and if $f^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{F}$ for all $A$ in some collection of sets $C$, then $f^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{F}$ for all $A \in \sigma(C)$.

Comment: Following up on the comment by @Michael, a useful technique for this and similar results is sometimes called the *good sets principle*. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2854237/13130) and [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22good+sets+principle%22&filter=0).