# What does it mean to say "the Lebesgue measure on an interval $I$"?

Tags: measure-theory

So I had two guesses:

1. The Lebesgue measure of all Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that are contained in $I$
2. Take the subspace topology of $I$ inherited from $\mathbb{R}$. Generated a Borel $\sigma$-algebra $B(I)$ on $I$. Then each $A\in B(I)$ is a Borel set of $\mathbb{R}$ so take the Lebesgue measure of $A$.

The difference between these two guesses is that a Borel set of $\mathbb{R}$ that is also contained in $I$ may probably not in $B(I)$.

Comment: It feels very strange that 1 and 2 should be different..., an example of this would be nice!

Comment: I think in general I could ask <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222810/borel-sigma-algebra-on-a-topological-subspace>

Comment: So... you found the answer, didn't you?

Comment: The answer is that they are the same. See a post on [a more general question][1]. 


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/222895/26655