# Result on subspace Borel $\sigma$-algebra: Sorgenfrey plane provides counterexample?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, borel-sets

Let $X\supseteq Y$ be sets, let $\tau$ be a topology on $X,$ and let $\tau_Y$ be the subspace topology on $Y;$ then
$$\sigma_Y(\tau_Y)=\{A\cap Y:A\in\sigma(\tau)\},$$
where for $Z\subseteq Y$ we define $\sigma_Y(Z)$ to be the $\sigma$-algebra generated, on $Y,$ by $Z.$ (This result is proved in e.g. [user642796's Math.Stackexchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/222895/279330).)

However, doesn't Example 4.12 in Wise & Hall's *Counterexamples in Probability and Real Analysis* contradict this result?
[image: WH E4.12]

(In the notation of the above example, our result says $\sigma_B(\tau_B)=\{A\cap B:A\in\sigma(\tau)\},$ so that every $C\in\sigma_B(\tau_B)$ is of the form $A\cap B$ with $A\in\sigma(\tau);$ but $B$ is closed and hence is in $\sigma(\tau),$ so $A\cap B\in\sigma(\tau),$ contradicting the statement of the Example.)

Maybe Wise & Hall made a mistake somewhere...

Comment: For the Sorgenfrey line $\Bbb S$ we do have that $\operatorname{Bor}(\Bbb S)=\operatorname{Bor}(\Bbb R)$ but this is no longer true for their squares $H$ and $\Bbb R^2$; the former has way more Borel sets, and is not the product $\sigma$-algebra of the factor spaces. I think that's the core issue. The identity for the $\sigma$-algebras of subspaces does hold, and $H$ is not a counterexample to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed an error: The Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $H$ properly contains the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\Bbb R^2$. This is clear from the fact that every subset of the reverse diagonal $y=-x$ is closed in $H$ and therefore a Borel set in $H$, but not every subset of the reverse diagonal is a Borel set in $\Bbb R^2$. For further explanation see the answer to [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/339991/borel-sigma-algebra-of-a-borel-subset).