# Measure Theory - Bogachev Vol I, Corollary 1.2.9

Tags: measure-theory

While reading Bogachev's Measure Theory Vol I, I've stumbled upon a bit I don't follow:
I don't understand the reasoning behind the very last sentence in the proof of Corollary 1.2.9 (see image below); namely, I don't see what follows from the second assertion nor do I understand the implication.

Would greatly appreciate some clarification!

Here's a link to a screencap of the relevant bits[image: Corollary 1.2.9]

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I think I've found the answer to this same question [on another thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7881/preimage-of-generated-sigma-algebra), so unless someone can think of a simpler solution i'd like to close this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the $\sigma$ algebra $\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{F}))$. By the second assertion

$$\mathcal G:=\{ A \subset X | f^{-1}(A) \in \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{F}))   \}$$
is a $\sigma$-algebra.

As  $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal G$ and $\mathcal G$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, you have

$$\sigma(\mathcal{F}) \subset \mathcal G \,.$$

Thus by the definition of $\mathcal G$ we have

$$f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{F})) \subset  \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{F})) $$

Comment: In the definition of $\mathcal{G}$ I think you mean $A$ is a subset of $X$, not a member. Anyway, I understand now. Thanks!

Comment: @Sai Yep, you are right, fixed.