# $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\pi$-system

Tags: probability-theory

Here is a problem from probability with martingales. I want to a better way of writing this than my waffle:

**Let $Y$ be a random variable and $\pi (\mathbb{R})$ is a $\pi$-system generating the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$, show that $Y^{-1}(\pi (\mathbb{R}))$ is $\pi$-system generating $\sigma(Y)$.**

I want to say something like this:

Showing it is a $\pi$ system is easy. inverse operations are preserved under taking a finite unions. Take a $B\in \sigma(Y)$ then $B=f^{-1}(B')$, for some $B'\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ here comes the waffle: **$B'$ is generated by some arbitrary unions/intersections of open sets and taking pre-image preserves taking unions/intersections. so $B$ is the unions and intersections of pre-image of sets in $\pi(\mathbb{R})$**

what is a neat way of saying this?

Comment: Do you know already that preimages of measurable sets form a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker yes but how is that related to this?

Comment: Well, one side is that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the preimages of sets in the $\pi$-system is not larger than the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Y$, and that follows directly from that fact.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker nope, i am trying to show the pre-image of the $\pi$-system is a $\pi$-system? i am interested in writing down the proof using rigorous language rather than the result itself.

Comment: You want to show that $\sigma\{Y^{-1}(B)\in\pi(\mathbb{R})\}=\sigma\{Y^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$ in a clean way, right?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker $\sigma\{Y^{-1}(B): B\in\pi(\mathbb{R}) \}=\sigma\{Y^{-1}(B): B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \}$, yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A neat way is to use [the following result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7881/preimage-of-generated-sigma-algebra):

> Let $\cal C$ be some collection of subsets of a set $Y$, and let $f$ be a function from some set $X$ to $Y$. I want to prove:
>   $$f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal C))=\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal C)).$$

Comment: so doing this rigorously require transfinite induction or not?

Comment: because what i wrote in bald is basically that. every borel set is 'generated' by repeatedly  taking intersections and unions.