# Proof that the preimage of generated $\sigma$-algebra is the same as the generated $\sigma$-algebra of preimage.

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

This question has also been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7881/preimage-of-generated-sigma-algebra), but the answer there didn't help me.

I am trying to prove that, given some measurable space $(X, \Sigma)$, if $G$ is a collection of subset of $X$ such that $\sigma(G) = \Sigma$, then
$$f^{-1}(\sigma(G)) = \sigma(f^{-1}(G)).$$
So far, I have been able to show that $\sigma(f^{-1}(G)) \subseteq f^{-1}(\sigma(G))$, but I am having trouble with the opposite inclusion. I have shown that $f^{-1}(G)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, from which it follows that $f^{-1}(G) \subseteq \sigma(f^{-1}(G))$, but that's about all I have been able to show. How do I proceed from there?

The answer in the other question suggests the following approach:
Prove that

- $f^{-1}(G) \in \sigma(f^{-1}(G))$,
- if $f^{-1}(A_i) \in \sigma(f^{-1}(G))$ for $i \in \mathbb{N}$ (i.e. a countable collection), then $f^{-1}(\bigcup_i A_i) \in \sigma(f^{-1}(G))$, and
- if $f^{-1}(A) \in \sigma(f^{-1}(G))$ then $f^{-1}(Y \setminus A) \in \sigma(f^{-1}(G))$.

However, I am not sure how to actually prove this, and even then, I'm not sure how it follows from this that $f^{-1}(\sigma(G)) \subseteq \sigma(f^{-1}(G))$.

Comment: $f^{-1}(G)$ is **not** a $\sigma$-algebra ($f^{1}(G)$ is a (sub)set; therefore it cannot be a $\sigma$-algebra since $\sigma$-algebras are - by definition- families of subsets). $f^{-1}(G) \in \sigma(f^{-1}(G))$ follows direclty from the definition of $\sigma(\cdots)$. And it might be helpful to add what exactly you do not understand about the linked answer. Otherwise it's pretty hard to write a helpful answer.

Comment: @saz I had a few errors in my question. I have tried to explain what I don't understand in the linked answer.

Comment: But the linked answer mentions also that you should use that the preimage operation commutes which set algebra operations, i.e. $$f^{-1} (Y \backslash A) = X \backslash f^{-1}(A)$$ and $$f^{-1} \left( \bigcup_i A_i \right) = \bigcup_i f^{-1}(A_i)$$ and $$f^{-1} \left( \bigcap_i A_i \right) = \bigcap_i f^{-1}(A_i).$$

Comment: @saz I think I see it now. I'm able to prove the second and third bullet, but I still don't see how I'm supposed to prove $f^{-1}(G) \in \sigma(f^{-1}(G))$. I swear I'm not being willfully obtuse, I just don't get it.

Comment: If $G$ is a collection of sets (again; note that you changed it; at the beginning you assumed that $G$ is a set), then you have to show $f^{-1}(G) \subseteq \sigma(f^{-1}(G))$, i.e. any set $A \in \sigma^{-1}(G)$ satisfies $A \in \sigma(f^{-1}(G))$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After working on it some more, I have come up with a proof. It follows the ideas of the question I linked, and uses the properties of preimage that saz listed in the comments. I also found out that the proof does not actually need the premise that $\sigma(\mathcal{G}) = \Sigma$, and it is in fact not even necessary that $X$ is a measurable space.

The proof is as follows. We wish to prove that $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{G})) \subseteq \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{G}))$.
  First we define
  $$D = \{G \subseteq Y \mid f^{-1}(G) \in \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{G}))\}.$$
  Observe that what we want to show will follow if we prove that
  $D$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and that $\mathcal{G} \subseteq D$.
  This is because it will imply that $\sigma(\mathcal{G}) \subseteq D$,
  which, by the definition of $D$, will imply that if $G \in \sigma(\mathcal{G})$,
  then $f^{-1}(G) \in \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{G}))$.
  This further implies that
  $$f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{G})) = \{f^{-1}(G) \mid G \in \sigma(\mathcal{G})\} \subseteq \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{G})).$$
  Hence, we now show that $D$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and that $\mathcal{G} \subseteq D$.
  First observe that $f^{-1}(\mathcal{G}) \subseteq \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{G}))$.
  This implies that if $G \in \mathcal{G}$ then $f^{-1}(G) \in \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{G}))$.
  By the definition of $D$, this further implies that $\mathcal{G} \subseteq D$.
  To show that $D$ is a $\sigma$-algebra,
  we verify properties of a $\sigma$-algebra.

- Since $\emptyset = f^{-1}(\emptyset)$ and
                           $\emptyset \in \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{G}))$,
                           we have $\emptyset \in D$.
- Assume $G \in D$. Then $f^{-1}(G) \in \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{G}))$.
                           Since $\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{G}))$ is closed under complement,
                           we get
                           $$X \setminus f^{-1}(G) = f^{-1}(Y) \setminus f^{-1}(G) = f^{-1}(Y \setminus G) = f^{-1}(G^c) \in \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{G})),$$
                           which implies that $G^c \in D$.
- Assume $G_1,G_2,\dots \in D$. Then for all $G_i$
                           we have $f^{-1}(G_1) \in \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{G}))$.
                           Since $\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{G}))$ is closed under
                           countable union, we get
                           $$\bigcup_i f^{-1}(G_i) = f^{-1}(\bigcup_i G_i) \in \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{G})),$$
                           which implies that $\bigcup_i G_i \in D$.

Comment: Please check and correct your notation for all the different $G$s you use. It is very confusing.

Comment: you're the man. that was excellent.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the following properties of $f^{-1}$:
$$
f^{-1}(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}G_i)=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}f^{-1}(G_i)\tag1
$$
$$
f^{-1}(\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}G_i)=\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}f^{-1}(G_i)\tag2
$$
$$
f^{-1}(G_i^c)=f^{-1}(G_i)^c\tag3
$$
Suppose $A\in \sigma(G)$ and $\:A=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}G_i,\:G_i\in G$, i.e. $A$ is formed by the countable union of sets in $G$. Then 
$$
f^{-1}(A)=f^{-1}(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}G_i)=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}f^{-1}(G_i)\in\sigma(f^{-1}(G))
$$
For $A\in \sigma(G)$ and $\:A=\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}G_i,\:G_i\in G$, i.e. $A$ is formed by the countable intersection of sets in $G$. Then 
$$
f^{-1}(A)=f^{-1}(\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}G_i)=\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}f^{-1}(G_i)\in\sigma(f^{-1}(G))
$$
For $A\in \sigma(G)$ and $\:A=G_i^c,\:G_i\in G$, i.e. $A$ is formed by the complement of set in $G$. Then 
$$
f^{-1}(A)=f^{-1}(G_i^c)=f^{-1}(G_i)^c\in \sigma(f^{-1}(G))
$$
$G_i\in \sigma(G)$ is again the countable union, intersection and complement of sets and so $f^{-1}(G_i)\in \sigma(f^{-1}(G))$. 
So we have
$$f^{-1}(\sigma(G)) \subseteq \sigma(f^{-1}(G))$$

Comment: But how would you show that $f^{-1}(G) \in \sigma(f^{-1}(G))$?

Comment: What do you mean? If G is a single set, then it is clear already

Comment: But $G$ is a collection of subsets. I can see why $f^{-1}(G) \subseteq \sigma(f^{-1}(G))$, but not why the same holds with $\in$.

Comment: G is the countable union, intersection and complement of open sets. Read proof again.

Comment: @mrp If $G$ is a collection of subsets, then it has to read $f^{-1}(G) \subseteq \sigma(f^{-1}(G))$ and **not** $f^{-1}(G) \in \sigma(f^{-1}(G))$. (Note that in the first version of your question you stated that $G$ is a set; not a collection of sets.)

Comment: I prove this by for any $A∈σ(G)$, if $f^{−1}(A)∈σ(f^{−1}(G))$, then $f^{-1}(\sigma(G)) \subseteq \sigma(f^{-1}(G))$.

Comment: @hermes I'm not sure what you mean by "open" in this context.

Comment: @hermes I'm afraid not. I have only heard of open sets in topology, and I have only seen $\sigma$-algebras defined as a collection of subsets that include the whole set and is closed under complement and countable union.

Answer (score 0):

mrp and hermes answers are great! I just want to add a solution which does not hinge on the construction of our $\sigma$-algebra as combinations of set operations but rather the definiton of our the sigma algebra of a set $G$ being the intersection of all sigma algebras containing $G$, or the smallest sigma algebra containing $G$.

$f^{-1}(\sigma(G))\subseteq \sigma (f^{-1}(G))$: Lets prove the contrapositive that $\neg (f^{-1}(\sigma(G))\supset \sigma (f^{-1}(G)))$. Assume $f^{-1}(\sigma(G))\supset \sigma (f^{-1}(G))$ and let $f^{-1}(\sigma(G))\setminus \sigma (f^{-1}(G))=\{f^{-1}(x_1),f^{-1}(x_2),...,f^{-1}(x_n),...\}$ for some $x_i \in \sigma(G)$. It follows that $f^{-1}(\sigma(G))\setminus \{f^{-1}(x_1),f^{-1}(x_2),...,f^{-1}(x_n),...\}=f^{-1}(\sigma(G)\setminus\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...\})$ this will ofcourse be the same as $\sigma(f^{-1}(G))$. Now as $\sigma(G)\setminus\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...\}$ is smaller than $\sigma(G)$ we must either (1) have that it does not contain $G$ or (2) its not a $\sigma$-algebra, the equality $f^{-1}(\sigma(G)\setminus\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...\})=\sigma (f^{-1}(S))$ rules out (2) so it must be that $\sigma(G)\setminus\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...\}$ is no $\sigma$-algebra, this means that there are sets $A_n$ in $\sigma(G)\setminus\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...\}$ such that $\bigcup_n A_n\notin \sigma(G)\setminus\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...\}$(or some $A\setminus B$) this means that $f^{-1}(\bigcup_n A_n)=\bigcup_n f^{-1}(A_n)\notin f^{-1}(\sigma(G)\setminus \{ x_1, x_2,...\})$ but $f^{-1}(A_n)$ must be in $\sigma(f^{-1}(G))$ as we otherwise would have removed it so $\bigcup_n f^{-1}(A_n)\in \sigma(f^{-1}(G))=f^{-1}(\sigma(G)\setminus \{ x_1, x_2,...\}$ a contradiction so our assumption must be wrong. This proves the inclusion

$f^{-1}(\sigma(G))\supseteq \sigma (f^{-1}(G))$: here it is enough to remember that the preimage of a $\sigma$-ring being a $\sigma$-ring so $f^{-1}(\sigma (G))$ is a $\sigma$-ring and as $G\subseteq\sigma (G)$ we also have $f^{-1}(G)\subseteq f^{-1}(\sigma(G))$ so $f^{-1}(\sigma(G))$ is a $\sigma$-ring containing $f^{-1}(G)$ from which it follows that $f^{-1}(\sigma(G))\supseteq \sigma(f^{-1}(G))$ as $\sigma(f^{-1}(G))$ is the smallest $\sigma$-ring containing $f^{-1}(G)$ $\square$

I am still fairly new to this area(the course started just over a week ago) so my argument may be messy, sorry about that. But i do think this is a nice alternative.