# How to proof that $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal C))\subseteq\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal C))$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a function, $\mathcal C$ be a family of subsets of $Y$. I am convinced that $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal C))=\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal C))$, where $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal A$.

The part $\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal C))\subseteq f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal C))$ is quite straight forward since $f^{-1}$ behave nicely with set-theoretic operations but I cannot see how to prove its converse. I tried to characterize $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ by seeing how it can be constructively define but my effort was not very fruitful. (From this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54172/the-sigma-algebra-of-subsets-of-x-generated-by-a-set-mathcala-is-the-s) by Mr.Asaf, it seems that I must use higher cardinal.)

So how should I prove $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal C))\subseteq\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal C))$ ? It is really hard or perhaps I missed something silly? Any hint would be appreciate. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have given a detailed answer of this [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496875/proof-that-the-preimage-of-generated-sigma-algebra-is-the-same-as-the-generat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $\mathcal A=\{E\subseteq Y:\; f^{-1}(E)\in \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal C)\}.$
Then it is not hard to see that $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Try to do it yourself. Since $\mathcal A$ contains $\mathcal C$, it contains the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal C$. Therefore $\sigma(\mathcal C)\subseteq \mathcal E$ so that 
$f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal F))\subseteq \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal C)).$

Comment: Who is $\epsilon$?