# Preimage of generated $\sigma$-algebra and the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the preimage

Tags: measure-theory

I'm working on proving the equality between the preimage of generated $\sigma$-algebra and generated $\sigma$-algebra of preimage.

I noticed that there's a duplicate: [Proof that the preimage of generated $\sigma$-algebra is the same as the generated $\sigma$-algebra of preimage.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496875/proof-that-the-preimage-of-generated-sigma-algebra-is-the-same-as-the-generat?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I'm failing to understand the proof in in the post, so I tried my own take and wanted some feedback:

I have proved two properties to help with this problem:

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a mapping.
If $\mathcal B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$, then 
$f^{-1}(\mathcal B)$={$f^{-1}(B):B \in \mathcal B$} is a $\sigma$-algebra on X, and that if $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on X, then $f_*$$\mathcal A$={$E\subset Y$:$f^{-1}(E)\in \mathcal A$} is a $\sigma$-algebra on Y.

Now I used the first property to show that if $\mathcal E$ is a collection of subsets of $Y$, $\sigma(f^{-1}$($\mathcal E$))$\subset f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal E))$ since  $f^{-1}$($\mathcal E$)$\subset f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal E))$, and $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal E))$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Now I want to show the other direction, and I think I just have to pick a 
'clever' $\mathcal A$. I tried both $\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal E))$, and $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal E))$ but didn't arrive at the conclusion I want.

How can I show $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal E)) \subset \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal E))$ using the second property above?

Comment: What does $\mathcal M$ stand for?

Comment: $\sigma$-algebra generated by a collection of sets. It's the notation used in Folland, but thanks for pointing it out, I'll change to $\sigma$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\{B \subset Y: f^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal M(f^{-1}(\mathcal E)\}$ is a sigma algebra by the second property. It contains $\mathcal E$, hence it contains $\mathcal M(\mathcal E)$. This is exactly what we are trying to prove.

Comment: I got to $\mathcal M(\mathcal E)$ being contained in the first set, but I'm not sure how that implies the conclusion that I am trying to get to.

Comment: What you have to show is $f^{-1}(D) \in \mathcal M( \mathcal f^{-1}( \mathcal E))$ if $D \in \mathcal M (\mathcal  E)$ and that is what we just proved.

Comment: So, by definition of the set, $\mathcal E$ is contained in it, consequently $\mathcal M(\mathcal E)$. Then for any $D \in \mathcal M(\mathcal E)$, $f^{-1}(D)\in \mathcal M(f^{-1}(\mathcal E))$. Thus $f^{-1}(\mathcal M(\mathcal E)) \subset \mathcal M(f^{-1}(\mathcal E))$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is the argument.

Comment: thank you, I understand now! Is my logic behind for the other direction of inclusion ok?

Comment: Yes, that part is fine.