# Proving if $X$ is a random variable and $f$ is a continuous function, then $f(X)$ is a random variable

Tags: statistics

I'm reading "Fundamental of Mathematical Statistics" by Gupta and Kapoor and the authors make the claim that "if $X$ is a random variable and $f$ is a continuous function, then $f(X)$ is a random variable". The proof has been skipped as it was beyond the scope of the textbook.

However, here's my question: There's not much information about given about $f$, so I assume $f$ is a real valued function on $\mathbb{R}$. So clearly the composition $f(X)$ is also a random variable. The hypothesis that $f$ is continuous is never used. So, does it mean that $f$ does not have be continuous? Or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: Could you provide the text in which this statement was found?

Comment: @KevinLi I've edited my question details.

Answer (score 4):

The proof is most likely out of the scope of most undergraduate mathematical statistics/probability courses.

Formally, a random variable is a measurable function from $ \Omega $ to $ E $ where
$ (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P) $ is a probability space and $ (E, \mathcal{E}) $
is a measurable space.

A well-known result in measure-theoretic probability is that if $ X : \Omega \to E $, and $ f : E \to E $ is
continuous, then $ f \circ X $ is also a measurable function with respect to the previous probability space. This is the result to which the authors are referring.

Comment: "A well-known result in measure-theoretic probability is..." Assuming $\mathcal E$ is the Borel sigma-algebra on $E$, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Composition of measurable functions results in a measurable function.

So it is enough for $f$ to be measurable as a function $f:(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)\to(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$ where $\mathcal B$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

So it boils down to the statement that **every continuous function is Borel-measurable**.

If $\tau$ denotes the topology on $\mathbb R$ then the continuity of $f$ assures that $f^{-1}(\tau)\subseteq\tau$.

From this it follows directly that: $$\sigma(f^{-1}(\tau))\subseteq\sigma(\tau)=\mathcal B$$

It is true in general that $$\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal A))=f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal A))$$

For a proof of that see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1903402/75923).

Applying this we find: $$f^{-1}(\mathcal B)=f^{-1}(\sigma(\tau))\subseteq\sigma(\tau)=\mathcal B$$stating exactly that $f$ is measurable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You're right that $f$ does not have to be continuous. It just merely needs to be [measurable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function). You can think of measurable functions as functions that can be approximated by continuous functions ([Lusin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem)). Measurable functions arise in the study of [Lebesgue integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration).

This case might be familiar to you as an undergraduate student (like me):

The Lebesgue Theorem for Riemann integration says that a function $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ if and only if the set of the discontinuities of $f$ is a [null-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set). So, this gives you a class of functions that are not necessarily continuous, but they're measurable.