# Every $\sigma$-algebra on a set contains that set?

Tags: measure-theory

I was looking at the answers given in
[$\sigma$-algebra generated by trace is trace of generated $\sigma$-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2927656). In the answers, it is assumed that if $\mathcal G$ is a family of subsets of $\Omega$ and $A\subseteq\Omega$ then $A\in \sigma(A\cap G)$. But why is this true?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, but $\Omega$ is not necessarily in $G$.

Comment: Not true. Tale $\mathcal G=\{\emptyset\}$ for a counter-example.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, But how did you get $A=A\cap\Omega\in \sigma(A\cap G)$? We can't use $A=A\cap\Omega\in A\cap \sigma( G)=\sigma(A\cap G)$ because we are trying to prove that $A\cap \sigma( G)=\sigma(A\cap G)$.

Comment: The statement is wrong and you are mis-quoting the proof in the link.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, "Every $σ$-algebra on set $E$ will contain set $E$ and $\sigma(\mathcal{E} \cap E)$ is a σ-algebra on set $E$." It is made by the author of the answer in the comments.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, How is it a mis-quote?

Comment: What is your definition of $\sigma$-algebra?  Usually this is just literally part of the definition.

Comment: Sigma algebra generated by a class of sets is meaningful only when the universal space is specified in advance. In think your confusion is only about the definition of $\sigma (A \cap G)$.

Comment: @EricWofsey, https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sigma-Algebra.html.

Comment: So your answer is part (1) of the definition: a $\sigma$-algebra on a set $X$ by definition contains $X$ as an element.

Comment: @EricWofsey, is $X$ here $\Omega$ or $A$?

Comment: That's the difference between [σ-ring and σ-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets#Related_structures). A σ-ring does not have to contain the whole set (ring unity), and σ-algebra is defined as σ-ring with it.

Comment: In this context, $\sigma(A\cap \mathcal{G})$ is being used to refer to the $\sigma$-algebra on $A$ generated by $A\cap \mathcal{G}$.  (It is a sloppy notation: it should really be written as something like $\sigma_A(A\cap\mathcal{G})$ to indicate the set on which the $\sigma$-algebra lives.)  So, $X$ would be $A$.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you would add all the relevant definitions to your question and your own attempts.