# The Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a metric space is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra with respect to which all continuous functionals are measurable

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm trying to solve *Theorem I.1.7* in Parthasarathy's textbook *Probability Measures on Metric Spaces*.

> Let $(E, d)$ be a metric space and $\mathcal B(E)$ its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Then $\mathcal{B}(E)$ coincides with $\mathcal A$ defined as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra with respect to which all continuous functionals on $E$ are measurable.

Could you verify if my attempt is fine?

I post my proof separately as below answer. This allows me to subsequently remove this question from unanswered list.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but wouldn't that imply that for every Banach space  $X$,  $\mathcal B(X)=σ(X^*)$. This fails for non separable Banach spaces https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24432/borelx-sigmax-for-x-non-separable.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. I'm not sure :v This theorem is also mentioned as Prop 1.3 in [this](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~vangaans/jancol1.pdf) lecture note. I hope that I quote the theorem correctly.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. OP is talking about all continuous functionals, i.e. not necessarily linear.

Comment: Oops, misread the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [*Lemma:*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4182181/prove-that-mathcal-c-subseteq-mathcal-py-implies-sigmaf-1-mat?noredirect=1&lq=1) Let $f:X \to Y$ and $C$ be some collection of subsets of $Y$. Then $$f^{-1}[\sigma(C)]=\sigma(f^{-1}[C]).$$

Let $\mathcal O$ be the standard topology of $\mathbb R$. Then $\sigma(\mathcal O)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb R$. Let $\mathcal C(E)$ the space of all all continuous functionals on $E$. Let
$$
f^{-1}[\sigma(\mathcal O)] := \{f^{-1}(B) \mid B \in \sigma(\mathcal O)\} \quad \forall f \in \mathcal C(E).
$$

Then $\mathcal A$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by
\begin{align}
\bigcup_{f \in \mathcal C(E)} f^{-1}[\sigma(\mathcal O)].
\end{align}

We have
\begin{align}
\mathcal A &= \sigma \left ( \bigcup_{f \in \mathcal C(E)}  f^{-1}[\sigma( \mathcal O )] \right ) \\
&= \sigma \left ( \bigcup_{f \in \mathcal C(E)} \sigma( f^{-1}[\mathcal O] ) \right ) \quad \text{by our Lemma} \\
& \subseteq \sigma \left (  \sigma \left ( \bigcup_{f \in \mathcal C(E)} f^{-1}[\mathcal O] \right) \right ) \\
&= \sigma \left ( \bigcup_{f \in \mathcal C(E)} f^{-1}[\mathcal O] \right) \\
&\subseteq \mathcal B(E).
\end{align}

Because metric space is perfectly normal. For each closed subset $F$ of $E$, there is a [continuous functional](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4433405/uniformly-continuous-map-that-separates-2-closed-subsets-with-positive-distanc) $f:E \to [0, 1]$ such that $F =f^{-1}(0)$. This implies $\mathcal A$ contains all closed and thus all open subsets of $E$. This completes the proof.