# Generator of $\sigma$-algebra generated by a subset

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space and let $\mathcal{G}$ be a generator of $\mathcal{F}$, i.e. $\sigma(\mathcal{G}) = \mathcal{F}$. For any subset $A \subset \Omega$ we can form the following $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega \cap A$:
$$\mathcal{F}  \cap A = \{B \cap A ~ | ~ B \in \mathcal{F} \} 
$$

I would like to show that $\mathcal{F}  \cap A$ is generated by the family $\mathcal{G} \cap A =  \{B \cap A ~ | ~ B \in \mathcal{G} \} $. It is straightforward to see that
$$
\sigma(\mathcal{G} \cap A) \subset \mathcal{F}\cap A
$$
since $\mathcal{F} \cap A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing all sets in the family $\mathcal{G} \cap A$. However, the reverse inclusion is harder to show - and I am not even sure if the statement holds. Any help/hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7881/preimage-of-generated-sigma-algebra?noredirect=1&lq=1) is what you are looking for. Just consider the map $f:A \to \Omega, x \mapsto x$.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed.